# Different voltage rails output filter does share same core

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, atx

I am reviewing circuit diagrams of ATX power supplies. I have noticed
this in almost all different designs of ATX power supplies. Different voltage power
rails output filter share a one core [ toroid ].

[image]

[image]

Is there is a specific reason for this or this is just to reduce the core size and 
number of components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's known as a [coupled inductor](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=slup082&fileType=pdf&track=no).

From a DC/steady-state standpoint, the behaviour is identical to independent inductors.

Under dynamic conditions, the coupled inductor provides numerous benefits (in addition to the lower parts count you mentioned):

- Improved transient response
- Improved cross regulation
- Ripple current steering
- Easier current limiting

Comment: I think I need to read that whole text Am I right?

Comment: It's a bit too much to include in an answer, so yes, please read the article.